# Filtrations and Sigma-Algebras

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have been practising a question set by my lecturer and try to verify the answer, unfortunately I am unable to understand the following question and answer.

$\textbf{Question:}$
Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}, \mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and $P(\{\omega\})=\tfrac{1}{3}$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$. Define a stochastic process $(X(t):t\ge 0)$ by $X(t)(\omega) = \max\{t-\omega,0\}.$ Then the filtration generated by the stochastic process $X$ computes as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F} = 
\begin{cases}
\{0,\Omega\}, \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{if $t\in[0,1],$} \\
\{0,\Omega,\{1\},\{2,3\}, \phantom{xx}\text{if $t \in (1,2]$,}\\
\mathcal{P}(\Omega), \qquad \qquad \qquad \phantom{.}\text{if $t>2$.} \end{cases}
\end{align}

Would anyone be able to briefly explain how the filtration was generated and how the $t$ interval was selected?

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to check that the random variable $X(t)$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F_t$ for each $t\ge0$.

If $t\in[0,1]$, the only value that $X(t)$ can take is $0$. So we need to find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $X^{-1}(t)(\{0\})=\Omega$. Such $\sigma$-algebra is $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.

If $t\in(1,2]$, the range of $X(t)$ is $\{0, t-1\}$. Then $X^{-1}(t)(\{0\})=\{2,3\}$ and $X^{-1}(t)(\{t-1\})=\{1\}$. The smallest $\sigma$-algebra is $\{\emptyset, \Omega,\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$.

If $t\in(2,3]$, the range of $X(t)$ is $\{0,t-1,t-2\}$, so that the $\sigma$-algebra must contain the sets $\{1\}$,$\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$. The smallest $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathcal P(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you say that if $t \in [0,1]$ then the only value $X(t)$ can take is $0$?

Comment: @JohnSmith Because $X(t)(\omega)=\max\{t-\omega,0\}=0$ if $t\in[0,1]$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: Unfortunately I still not following 100%. What value did $\omega$ assume in your last comment? ($max\{t-\omega\}$) ?

Comment: @JohnSmith We have a random variable $X(t):\Omega\to\mathbb R$ such that $\omega\mapsto\max\{t-\omega,0\}$ for each $t\ge0$. In our case, $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$ and $X(t)(1)=\max\{t-1,0\}$, $X(t)(2)=\max\{t-2,0\}$ and $X(t)(3)=\max\{t-3,0\}$. For any $t\in[0,1]$, $X(t)(1)=X(t)(2)=X(t)(3)=0$.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies. Could you explain the same logic (as you did in the above comment) for $X^{-1}(t)(\{0\})=\{2,3\}$ please?

Comment: @JohnSmith No problem. We have the same random variable, but now $t\in(1,2]$. Hence, $X(t)(1)=t-1$ and $X(t)(2)=X(t)(3)=0$. The random variable $X(t)$ takes two values ($0$ or $t-1$) if $t\in(1,2]$. We need to check that the preimages of the sets $\{0\}$ and $\{t-1\}$ belong to $\mathcal F_t$. $X^{-1}(t)(\{0\})=\{2,3\}$ (since $X(t)(2)=X(t)(3)=0$) and $X^{-1}(t)(\{t-1\})=\{1\}$ (since $X(t)(1)=t-1$). The smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ is $\{\emptyset,\Omega,\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$.

Comment: Ah! It is now clear, many thanks.